# Python GET request not matching CURL output

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am working with the SAXO OpenAPI. I need to authenticate using some non-confidential credentials as a first step of the authentication flow.

The following CURL request works fine and returns the response that I expect

```
curl -X GET -H “Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded” "https://sim.logonvalidation.net/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=37656c896c424f8cab64774e603bc927&state=y90dsygas98dygoidsahf8sa&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FmyAppTest"
```

However, when I try to do the same request in python, I get a status code 400 signaling an error. This is my python code

```
import requests

def authenticate(config: dict = None):
    if config is None:
        return False

    endpoint = config['AuthorizationEndpoint']
    head = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    data = {'response_type': 'code',
            'client_id': config['client_id'],
            'state': 'y90dsygas98dygoidsahf8sa',
            'redirect_uri': config['url']}
    response = requests.request('GET', url=endpoint, data=data, headers=head)
    print(response)

config = {'AuthorizationEndpoint': 'https://sim.logonvalidation.net/authorize',
          'client_id': '37656c896c424f8cab64774e603bc927',
          'url': 'http://localhost/myAppTest'}

authenticate(config)
```

I thought that the python code should have done the same request as in CURL, but apparently something is different. Can you tell me in what they differ?

Answer (score 2):

The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests have the data encoded right in the URL. You put the data inside a dictionary and is posting it in the body like an `application/json` request.

Replacing the endpoint URL with the URL of the curl should do the trick.

```
import requests

def authenticate(config: dict = None):
    if config is None:
        return False

    endpoint = config['AuthorizationEndpoint']
    head = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    response = requests.request('GET', url=endpoint, headers=head)
    print(response)

config = {'AuthorizationEndpoint': '"https://sim.logonvalidation.net/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=37656c896c424f8cab64774e603bc927&state=y90dsygas98dygoidsahf8sa&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FmyAppTest"',
          'client_id': '37656c896c424f8cab64774e603bc927',
          'url': 'http://localhost/myAppTest'}

authenticate(config)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your python code you are sending data as a body of a request, but you should send it as a query params. Try this:

```
response = requests.request('GET', url=endpoint, params=data, headers=head)
```

or

```
response = requests.get(url=endpoint, params=data, headers=head)
```